# Authorization Token for Azure Security Center to dismiss the alerts

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-security, securitycenter

I am trying to dismiss the alerts using API. I am following this link [Alert Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/updateresourcegrouplevelalertstatetodismiss) .
Now I am able to dismiss the alert using this link successfully but I have tried using PostMan and I failed, After looking into the documentation I got to know that I will need the Authorization Token to do this using PostMan but I don't know how can I create or obtain one.
Does anyone know how to create the Token specifically for Azure Security Center?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!
Anmol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#acquire-an-access-token) about acquiring an access token. You could use [`auth-code-flow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get access_token.

1.Request an authorization code

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&state=12345
```

2.Request an access token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code= {code acquired above}
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps. This secret needs to be URL-Encoded.
```

Note: `scope` is mentioned from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/alerts/updateresourcegrouplevelalertstatetodismiss).

[image]